# How to Get the Value of a List Type Property using propertyInfo

Tags: c#, reflection, asp.net-mvc-5, action-filter

```
            private static void Getproperties(Object Model) {
            Type objType = Model.GetType();
            PropertyInfo[] properties = objType.GetProperties();
            foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
            {
                object propValue;
                //Checking if property is indexed                 
                if(property.GetIndexParameters().Length ==0)
               propValue  = property.GetValue(Model,null);
                else
                {  
                 // want to retrieve collection stored in property index not passing 0 index returning element at 0 location ,how can i get whole list  
                 propValue = property.GetValue(objectModel,new Object[]{0});                       
                 }
                var elems = propValue as IList;
                 .... }
```

How can i get the Property Value of List Type, my property in the Model is a List Type for Example my Model contains a List Property

```
List<User>
```

wants to create a Filter and add to action on which i can check for potential Xss Attack ,whether model contains any such attack

Answer (score 4):

You don't really need this overload with second parameter. What you really need is to cast `object` returned by `.GetValue()` method back to type `List<T>`. Example :

```
class MyClass
{
    public List<int> MyProperty { get { return new List<int>() { 3, 4, 5, 6 }; } }
}

class Program
{        
    static void Main()
    {
        MyClass instance = new MyClass();
        PropertyInfo info = instance.GetType().GetProperty("MyProperty");

        List<int> another = info.GetValue(instance) as List<int>;

        for (int i = 0; i < another.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(another[i] + "   ");
        }
    }
}
```

Output : `3  4  5  6`

Comment: what if Instance and property name is not known, i wanted to create this as generic Based on the Model passed

Comment: If i understand correctly, you want to get T argument from property via reflection and cast value to this type. The problem is that generic type parameters are inferred on compile time. All operations with reflection are real-time operations so it suggests that we can't use generics to work with dynamicly fetched data.

Answer (score 0):

Check this one.

```
      List<string> sbColors = new List<string>();
      Type colorType = typeof(System.Drawing.Color);
      PropertyInfo[] propInfoList = colorType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public);
      foreach (PropertyInfo c in propInfoList)
      {
         sbColors.Add(c.Name);
      }
```